# Line class intersectionWith method implemantion

Tags: java, line

hello I need to implemnt the follwing method of Line class, in java:

```
// Returns the intersection point if the lines intersect,
// and null otherwise.
public Point intersectionWith(Line other) { }
```

I am afraid I am not farmiler with the math calcuations involoved.
can someone may help or reffer me to a place I can understand?
regards!

Comment: *[insert copy pasta about how javascript and java are like paintings and paint]*

Comment: What Line class are you talking about? Did you create your own Line class? If so, please provide it so we can better answer you

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also, -1 from me for lack of research effort, and for lack of effort in formulating the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are using Lines and Point that you created yourself and that are in 2D. If your Lines are defined by the equation **y = a*x + b**, and you store the coefficient **a** and **b**, then the intersection between two lines would be **(x,y)** such that **y == a1*x + b1 == a2*x + b2**

You can find **x** as: **x = (b2 - b1) / (a1 - a2)**
Note that there is no solution if **a1 == a2**, that is, if the two lines are parallel. 
Then, you can compute **y = a1*x + b1**